# Get destructured object from function parameters as a single object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I like using destructure parameters in my functions but occasionally I want to get the entire object passed without reconstructing it.

```
function foo({a, b, c, d, e}) {
   // How to get obj here?
}
foo(obj);
```

How can I get `obj` without resorting to:

```
let obj = {a, b, c, d, e}
```

The `arguments` variable is probably the key but it's an array(-like) object without the names.

Comment: Why not just write `function foo(obj) { const {a, b, c, d, e} = obj; ... }`?

Comment: `arguments[0]` will give you the object, but really you just should do the destructuring separately (not in the parameter declaration)

Comment: *"The arguments variable is probably the key but it's an array(-like) object without the names."* - Your function only has one parameter which is the object that you want (as Bergi said).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that is the correct answer.